# Integrating ads in my Android application

Tags: android, feed, ads

I would like to integrate a some text advertisements in my Android application.

I would like to know how we can listen to some feeds and display it on my Textview.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use of the ads networks. They provide their own api, so you need only to integrate them:

1. [smaato.com](http://smaato.com/)
2. [mobclix.com](http://mobclix.com/)
3. [admob.com](http://admob.com)

and you can google some others.

Comment: The thing is that i have not yet published my apk. The above links ask me for a application ID in the market.

Comment: You don't have to publich, just upload one as a draft.

Comment: i dint understand `just upload one as a draft` can you tell me how to do that..?

Comment: Upload an application to the market and don't click "Publish", click "Save" instead.